# PDO and CASE statements

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, case

In an application I'm building, I need to check whether a user has filled in certain fields on their profile, and if not, perform an action.

To find out whether the fields are filled in, I wrote the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS userComplete FROM Users 
        WHERE userID = :userID 
        AND userField1 IS NOT NULL
        AND userField2 IS NOT NULL";
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':userID', $this->_userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);    //Returning a single column
$this->_user_profile_complete = $result;
```

The query returns a single column, userComplete. Since Users has userID as the primary key, there should never be more than one of each userID, thus returning a count of 1 or 0, which I can use as true/false.

This worked, but I was interested to see whether I could make 100% sure I would only ever get 1 or 0. So I modified my query thusly:

```
$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN 1 
        ELSE CASE WHEN count(*) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE 0 END END AS userComplete FROM Users 
        WHERE userID = ':userID' 
        AND userField1 IS NOT NULL
        AND userField2 IS NOT NULL";
```

Using a CASE statement to compare the count to the expected values, I return 1 or 0 exclusively.

When given a userID, and executed directly through SSMS (by copying the query, and replacing :userID with an actual userID), both the first and second queries work. However, when run through the application, only the first query works. The second query fails with the following error:

> 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 0. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.'

According to the stack trace, the exception is thrown when PDO tries to execute(). What about the second statement is causing this error?

Comment: Could it be the 3rd line has `END END` I'm not too familiar with sql cases but that seems odd from a sanity check perspective.

Comment: The select case is unnecessary. Your first query is perfectly fine and will outperform the second.

Comment: @ryantxr Good to know! It was more out of interest than anything else - I saw a different way of doing it, and was curious whether it would work, and confused when it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a nested case statement? If the count is greater than zero, you want to return one and zero otherwise. Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END AS userComplete FROM Users 
        WHERE userID = ':userID' 
        AND userField1 IS NOT NULL
        AND userField2 IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: That's a good improvement, but gives the same error, I'm afraid.

Comment: @FelixPamittan The error quoted at the end of my question 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 0. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.'